# Touchesmoved method should read the UIbutton title

Tags: objective-c

I have 10 buttons on a **UIView**. if I swipe on the buttons starting from button 1 to 10 without removing my finger, I want to read the title label of the buttons as the finger moves on each button. Just imagine a swipe keyboard.

Is there a better approach instead of touches moved?